# If there is a fixed number of each character type, how do you calculate the number of permutations of passwords?

Tags: combinatorics

If your password generation says you *must* have 4 lowercase characters, 4 uppercase characters and 8 numbers arranged in any order, how do you calculate the number of possible combinations?

I ask this because I found [this password generator script](https://github.com/kunaludapi/Strong-Random-Password-Generator-Microsoft-Powershell/blob/master/New-RandomPassword.ps1) which provides that method of specifying password parameters.

e.g. `Get-RandomPassword.ps1 -SmallLetter 4 -CapitalLetter 4 -Number 8 -Symbol 0`

My gut is that this reduces the entropy, but I'd like to do the maths to confirm it. I just can't figure out the calculation to do!

I tried to use [the answer to this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33205/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-possible-passwords) as inspiration. If one possible arrangement of character types is LLLLUUUUNNNNNNNN, then that would result in:

`26^4 * 26^4 * 10^8 = 2.0882706e+19`

My logic then was that you could calculate the number of possible orderings, which I think is 16! So:

`26^4 * 26^4 * 10^8 * 16! = 4.3692448e+32`

But that's higher than if there was no restriction on the characters:

`(26+26+10)^16 = 4.7672402e+28`

That maths doesn't match my gut, so I'm looking to you to try to help me understand how to calculate the number of possible passwords that could be generated when the amount of each of the character types is fixed.

Comment: I did it [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/62921/18298) a while ago. Hope it helps your cause.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with the first part: `26^4 * 26^4 * 10^8`

You are not correct with the second part: `16!`

The first part chooses all of the characters to use, but note that the `16!` part does not take into account the fact that the order of the first digit (`a`) and the second digit (`b`) does not matter.

Example: it does not matter if it is `ab` or `ba`

The second part is, then, `16 choose 4 * 12 choose 4 * 8 choose 8 = 900900` (note that it doesn't matter which order you do the multiplication: `16 choose 8 * 8 choose 4 * 4 choose 4 = 900900` too)

The number of permutations is `(26^4 * 26^4 * 10^8) * (16 choose 4 * 12 choose 4 * 8 choose 8) = 1.881323e+25`

This is `2.0882706e+19 < 1.881323e+25 << 4.7672402e+28` and your intuition is correct